# My C-Code runs slowly in Mac comparing to Ubuntu

Tags: c, performance, macos, gcc

I have written a scientific code in C. I compile the code in Ubuntu using gcc 4.7.2, and in MBP using gcc 4.2. My Makefile looks like this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -c -fPIC -Wall -O3 -lpthread -g
BaseDir = /Users/admin/
libName = libTTVS.so
Include = -I$(BaseDir)UMFPACK/Include -I$(BaseDir)AMD/Include -I$(BaseDir)SuiteSparse_config
Lib = -L$(BaseDir)UMFPACK/Lib -L$(BaseDir)AMD/Lib -L$(BaseDir)SuiteSparse_config -L$(BaseDir)GotoBLAS2
AddFiles = -lumfpack -lamd -lsuitesparseconfig -lgoto2
StaticLibs = $(BaseDir)UMFPACK/Lib/libumfpack.a $(BaseDir)AMD/Lib/libamd.a $(BaseDir)SuiteSparse_config/libsuitesparseconfig.a $(BaseDir)GotoBLAS2/libgoto2.a
all: AlgebraFuncs.o QSP.o UpdateAlgVars.o AlgVarsJac.o ExtraRoutines.o SolveMultiStepSolverC.o TTVS.o TTVS.h
        $(CC) $(Include) $(Lib) $(AddFiles) -shared -lpthread -o $(libName) $^ -lm -g $(StaticLibs)

AlgebraFuncs.o: AlgebraFuncs.c TTVS.h
        $(CC) $(Include) $(CFLAGS) $^

QSP.o: QSP.c TTVS.h
        $(CC) $(Include) $(CFLAGS) $^

UpdateAlgVars.o: UpdateAlgVars.c TTVS.h
        $(CC) $(Include) $(CFLAGS) $^

AlgVarsJac.o: AlgVarsJac.c TTVS.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^

ExtraRoutines.o: ExtraRoutines.c TTVS.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^

SolveMultiStepSolverC.o: SolveMultiStepSolverC.c TTVS.h
        $(CC) $(Include) $(CFLAGS) $^

TTVS.o: TTVS.c TTVS.h
        $(CC) $(Include) $(CFLAGS) $^
```

As you can see, I use -O3 to compile the source code.

The problem is that the compiled code is very slow in Mac. In Ubuntu, the code is executed in 0.89sec, while in MBP, it takes 7.8sec. I have also implemented the code in MATLAB and here it is the results: Ubuntu: 4sec, MBP: 5.5sec.
As you can see, the C-code runs even slower than MATLAB which does not make sense.
Although gcc version is not the same in two platforms, I expect they at least be close. My main problem is that I do not even where to start to work around the problem or what I should check.

Here it is specs of two machines:
Ubuntu: Core i7 2600 @3.4GHz, Quad-Core, 8GB Ram
MBP: Core i5 @2.5GHz, 8GB Ram

I know that Ubuntu has more powerful CPU, but considering MATLAB results, I cannot see why C-code is much faster in Ubuntu. It should be faster, but not 8 times !!

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Is it the same system?  Two different machines? What specs?  Same CPU(s)/core(s), RAM, etc.?  Showing a makefile isn't going to help much here.

Comment: Also remember that MATLAB is extremely optimized when it comes to mathematics so it being faster is really not that impossible.

Comment: @Jensd Ok. I agree, MATLAB is highly optimized. But C-code in ubuntu easily beats MATLAB. So, I expect to see same behaviour in Mac.

Comment: There's plenty of C code out there that runs sloooow since its just bad. 3.4 GHz vs 2.5 GHz means quite a difference in speed hence the difference in the MATLAB results. 0.89 to 7.8 sec implies something else though. Try to profile to see what individual calls are slower on MBP.

Answer (score 3):

You're using an old compiler that does not have optimization support for the instructions your CPU supports. Try using Clang instead, Apple stopped supporting GCC some time ago and switched to this compiler in the new versions of Xcode.