# Clang error while creating shared library

Tags: gcc, llvm, clang, llvm-clang

I want to compile a shared library on MBP and based on the advise given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16117462/my-c-code-runs-slowly-in-mac-comparing-to-ubuntu), I have switched to `clang` (from `gcc`) to create the shared library. My `makefile` is:

```
CC = clang
CFLAGS = -c -fPIC -Wall -O3 -lpthread -g
BaseDir = /Users/admin/Prog/
Include = -I$(BaseDir)UMFPACK/Include -I$(BaseDir)AMD/Include -I$(BaseDir)SuiteSparse_config
Lib = -L$(BaseDir)UMFPACK/Lib -L$(BaseDir)AMD/Lib -L$(BaseDir)GotoBLAS2 -L$(BaseDir)SuiteSparse_config
AddFiles = -lumfpack -lamd -lgoto2 -lsuitesparseconfig
StaticLibs = $(BaseDir)GotoBLAS2/libgoto2.a $(BaseDir)UMFPACK/Lib/libumfpack.a $(BaseDir)AMD/Lib/libamd.a $(BaseDir)SuiteSparse_config/libsuitesparseconfig.a

all: TDS.o TDSJac.o ExtraRoutines.o CalcVFC.o TDS.h
        $(CC) $(Include) $(Lib) $(AddFiles) -dynamiclib -lpthread -o libTDS.so $^ -lm -g $(StaticLibs)

TDS.o: TDS.c TDS.h
        $(CC) $(Include) $(CFLAGS) $^

TDSJac.o: TDSJac.c TDS.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^

ExtraRoutines.o: ExtraRoutines.c TDS.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^

CalcVFC.o: CalcVFC.c TDS.h
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^

MexFile: TDSGateway.c
        mex -g -largeArrayDims -ldl TDSGateway.c

Move:
        mv libTDS.so ../../
        mv TDSGateway.mexmaci64 ../../
```

What I do here is:
1) Only compile `TDS.c`, `TDSJac.c`, `ExtraRoutines.c`, and `CalcVFC.c` to create four corresponding object files.
2) Merging object files and creating a shared library using following command:

```
clang -I(Some folders) -L(Some folders) -l(Some libraries) -shared -lpthread -o libTDS.so TDS.o TDSJac.o ExtraRoutines.o CalcVFC.o TDS.h -lm -g
clang: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files
```

As I am absolutely new to clang, I do not know what is wrong with Makefile. (If I replace `CC=clang` with `CC=gcc`, everything works good.)
I searched the internet with no success. Manual page of clang says nothing about shared library. I could not even get anything out of clang [homepage](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html). It is appreciated if help me to work around this problem.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I had yesterday almost the same problem.
But i never used cmake. I'm using an own makefile system of my company, so I just can tell you, what fixed the problem for me so far.

Clang has still some trouble with giving you the right hints on errorcase.
The linking error was:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/crt1.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `_DYNAMIC' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
```

I solved the problem as I figgered out, that the -shared Parameter has to be behind the -o X.o parameters. As I see this is not made in your case, too. You should try that first.

In our case I also had to parse the LFlags with -WL, or -L, (afaik it doesn't matter which one you take but I read about a clang bug in relation to -Wl,).
But idk in how far you have to parse LFlags or not, when using cmake.

Answer (score 1):

You've listed headers (`TDS.h`) as dependencies, which is fine, but you've then used `$^` as inputs, which includes *all* dependencies. You should not list a header as an input. It should not be on the command-line at all, and in `clang` this is actually an error.

The error message is obscure but easy to resolve. You have 2 choices:

1. Be explicit instead of using `$^`. You could use a variable for inputs and another for dependencies, e.g.; or
2. Use intermediate `.o` files instead of `.c` files as inputs to a `.so`. The `*.o` files can depend on any `.h` they include.